# Question about bitmasks and how i can extract 7 bits from a 16bit sequence in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitmask

i came across bitmasks to a code that i am making , but since i am a newbie and its the first time practising with bitmasks i want to understand them better.

So i have an example, that i want to get the first 7 bits of a 16 bit number that is unsigned short int type ,store them into a new integer and print them in decimal. I have tried the code below but i get random results. I would appreciate any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
unsigned short int num,mask1=127,final1;


scanf("%hx",&num);
printf("%hx\n",num);



final1=num&(mask1>>9);  

printf("Final is %hu\n",final1);

    return 0;
}
```

So for example when i put a random hex value like **0x3f23**
the bit sequnce is **0011111**100100011 . So i want to get the 7 first bits extracted which is my case is **0011111** . My initial thought was to use bit shift to the right to move the first 7 bits to the end of the sequence like this (which means 9 bits to the right)  000000000**0011111** but since i am a newbie i have trouble getting a proper result from the above thought

Comment: Note that `for (i=0;i<=8;i++)` will iterate 9 times. Also, each iteration of `final1 = num & (mask1 >> 1)` does exactly the same thing. The first 7 (leftmost) bits are `num >> 9` for a 16-bit value. Oh, and `%x` is expecting `unsigned int` not `unsigned short`, so there is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Wouldnt will iterate 9 times by 1 bit to the right? My thought was to move the 7 first bits that i want to the right using shift in order to have only the bits i want in the final1

Comment: The code i am making is to get a hex value that is formates like this 0x7f03 (not bigger not smaller) , and from its bits to get the 7 first bits and store it into a new unsigned short int and by the task i am required to use unsigned short int. By these info what do you suggest to change in the code ?

Comment: Use `scanf("%hx", &num);` and `final1 = num >> 9;`. Look out for compiler warnings.

Comment: @WeatherVane i changed the scanf, but when i try the value '0x3f06' i always get 0 as final output. I also replaced the for loop with this 'final1=num&(mask1>>8);'  and whatever value i put like 8 or 6 or 9, i get 0. My thought was to bit shift the 7 first bits to the end of the sequence which means i need to bitshift by 9 bits the 7 first bits since the number is 16 bits. What else do you suggest to change? Thanks, i am looking forward to your reply

Comment: Your `mask1 >> 8` is `0`. Instead of describing the code, please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for getting back to me, i updated my post above and added more details that i think would be useful. Let me know if you need me to provide any other details. Thank you once again for yournprecious time

Comment: Please chnage `final1 = num & (mask1 >> 9);` to `final1 = num >> 9;`